# macOS NSTableView grid borderwidth

Tags: swift, macos, border, cell, nstableview

I have a simple question. 
in IOS i used this simple line in storyboard to change cell border width:

```
  cell.layer.borderWidth = 6
```

if i do the same thing in a macOS app, cell border Width doesn't change.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {


     let cell = tableViewa.makeView(withIdentifier:  NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Cell"),owner: self ) as! Cell

        cell.layer?.masksToBounds = true
        cell.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
       cell.layer?.borderWidth = 2.0

    }
```

I tried in many different ways, searched on internet but the result it's still the same.
There's a method i can use to change cell border width?

how can i change grid/cell border width in macOS?

Comment: Do you want cell borders or a grid?

Comment: the separator between rows...i think it's grid

Comment: Did you check if `NSTableView` has methods or properties to change the grid?

Comment: No, there isn't a property to change grid border width

Comment: Does `cell` have a layer?